# Class 'Oureastudios\Laravel\BraintreeServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Kindly help me, I am new in Laravel framework

When I run my laravel project, it display error

> [Class 'Oureastudios\Laravel\BraintreeServiceProvider' not found].

I also try and load through composer but composer not download and give error.

```
composer require oureastudios/laravel5-braintree:dev-master --prefer-dist
```

> You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
>   ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
>     - Installing oureastudios/laravel5-braintree (dev-master 16ebcc6): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download
>   oureastudios/laravel5-braintree from dist: The
>   "https://api.github.com/repos/oureastudios/laravel5-braintree/zipball/16ebcc610d9d0efef8a4ec28c19c8123586f10c2"
>   file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
>       Now trying to download from source
>     - Installing oureastudios/laravel5-braintree (dev-master 16ebcc6): Cloning 16ebcc610d
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.
>
> [RuntimeException]   Failed to clone
>   https://github.com/oureastudios/laravel5-braintree.git, git was not
>   found, check that it is install   ed and in your PATH env.
>
> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress]
>   [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev]
>   [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies]
>   [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest]
>   [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your issue fixed, if so please mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

that repository doesnt exist anymore.

try this one instead
`https://github.com/odannyc/laravel5-braintree`

```
composer require odannyc/laravel5-braintree:dev-master --prefer-dist
```

Comment: Thank you, I run above command odannyc/braintree download successfully, but still same code display.  Class 'Oureastudios\Laravel\BraintreeServiceProvider' not found

Comment: @MohammadNazim remove that line in the providers declarations in `config/app.php` and do the proper installation of the package as described in the readme of the github